Is the State Space Weak* Dense in the Dual Space
Let $A$ be a C$^*$-algebra. Let $S(A)$ be the state space on $A.$ Is the span of $S(A)$ weak$^*$ dense in $A^*,$ the space of norm-bounded linear functionals? That is, for every functional $f\in A^*,$ does there exist a net of states $f_\lambda\in \mathrm{span}(S(A))$ s.t. $\lim_\lambda f_\lambda(a)=f(a)$ for every $a\in A?$
My attempt: Since $A$ is a Banach space, a vector subspace of $A^*$ is weak$^*$ dense iff it separates points in $A$. But we know that the state space separates points, so its span must be weak$^*$ dense.

Your reasoning is correct. Here is a reference to the fact that states separate the points

While, as noted by Evangelopoulos, your reasoning is correct, the result is far weaker than what it could have been. In fact, every bounded linear functional on $A$ can be written as a linear combination of four states (in particular, you don’t need to take the weak$^\ast$ closure). This follows from the existence of Jordan decompositions of bounded linear functionals, which can be found in, say, Proposition III.2.1 of Theory of Operator Algebras I by Takesaki.

Yes, I realized this a bit after I had asked. It is then plain to prove the result I actually wanted: that the span of the pure states are weak$^$ dense, since they are weak$^$ in the state space.
